# Payment Methods are not showing on PWA Suite?

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3, pwa-studio

> I have installed PWA suite on my local machine.
>
> I have enabled COD and Check / Money order Payment methods.
>   But Why these methods are not showing on checkout page. Pay with Card only displaying!
>
> Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you probably have a custom module that overrides the payment method. try to disable those module and check if it works

Comment: @magefms I haven't overridden anything yet. I'm just trying on plain magento with sample data.! Payments methods are displaying on magento instance. I'm facing issue with PWA suite.

Comment: Were you able to sort this out?

Comment: What is the solution to this @SainadhMannem i am facing the same issue.

Comment: No @gabrieliri I haven't got the solution.

Comment: @SubhasTakhellambam I don't have the solution.

Comment: Actually Magento didn't finish this yet, the work around for this would be to redirect the customer to the M2 frontend for cart and checkout.

Answer (score 0):

@sainadh I was also getting the same issue and in my case, no payment methods are showing in venia PWA with magento2.4.1 EE.

Did you resolve[image] this issue?

Comment: Hi Vivek,  did you get any solution to this issue? can you share if yes?